# How to read directories and sub-directories without knowing the directory name in perl?

Tags: perl

Hi i want to read directories and sub-directories without knowing the directory name. Current directory is "D:/Temp". 'Temp' has sub-directories like 'A1','A2'. Again 'A1' has sub-directories like 'B1','B2'. Again 'B1' has sub-directories like 'C1','C2'. Perl script doesn't know these directories. So it has to first find directory and then read one file at a time in dir 'C1' once all files are read in 'C1' it should changes to dir 'C2'. I tried with below code here i don't want to read all files in array(@files) but need one file at time. In array @dir elements should be as fallows.

```
$dir[0] = "D:/Temp/A1/B1/C1"
$dir[1] = "D:/Temp/A1/B1/C2"
$dir[2] = "D:/Temp/A1/B2/C1"
```

Below is the code i tried.

```
    use strict;
    use File::Find::Rule;
    use Data::Dumper;

    my $dir = "D:/Temp";
    my @dir = File::Find::Rule->directory->in($dir);
    print Dumper (\@dir);
    my $readDir = $dir[3];
    opendir ( DIR, $readDir ) || die "Error in opening dir $readDir\n";
    my @files = grep { !/^\.\.?$/ } readdir DIR;
    print STDERR "files: @files \n\n";

    for my $fil (@files) {
        open (F, "<$fil");
        read (F, my $data);
        close (F);
        print "$data";
    }
```

Comment: Is there a "D:/Temp/A1/B2/C2"?

Comment: Consider adding the **recursion**, **filesystems** and **windows** tags to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your Goal:** Find the absolute paths to those directories that do *not* themselves have child directories.

I'll call those directories of interest **terminal directories**. Here's the prototype for a function that I believe provides the convenience you are looking for. The function returns its result as a list.

```perl
my @list = find_terminal_directories($full_or_partial_path);
```

And here's an implementation of `find_terminal_directories()`. Note that this implementation does *not* require the use of any **global variables**. Also note the use of a private helper function that is called **recursively**.

On my Windows 7 system, for the input directory **C:/Perl/lib/Test**, I get the output:

```
== List of Terminal Folders ==
c:/Perl/lib/Test/Builder/IO
c:/Perl/lib/Test/Builder/Tester
c:/Perl/lib/Test/Perl/Critic

== List of Files in each Terminal Folder: ==
c:/Perl/lib/Test/Builder/IO/Scalar.pm
c:/Perl/lib/Test/Builder/Tester/Color.pm
c:/Perl/lib/Test/Perl/Critic/Policy.pm
```

**Implementation**

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Cwd qw(abs_path getcwd);

my @dir_list = find_terminal_directories("C:/Perl/lib/Test");
print "== List of Terminal Directories ==\n";
print join("\n", @dir_list), "\n";

print "\n== List of Files in each Terminal Directory: ==\n";
for my $dir (@dir_list) {
    for my $file (<"$dir/*">) {
        print "$file\n";
        open my $fh, '<', $file or die $!;
        my $data = <$fh>;  # slurp entire file contents into $data
        close $fh;

        # Now, do something with $data !
    }
}

sub find_terminal_directories {
    my $rootdir = shift;

    my @wanted;
    my $cwd = getcwd();
    chdir $rootdir;
    find_terminal_directories_helper(".", \@wanted);
    chdir $cwd;
    return @wanted;
}

sub find_terminal_directories_helper {
    my ($dir, $wanted) = @_;
    return if ! -d $dir;
    opendir(my $dh, $dir) or die "open directory error!";
    my $count = 0;
    foreach my $child (readdir($dh)) {
        my $abs_child = abs_path($child);
        next if (! -d $child || $child eq "." || $child eq "..");
        ++$count;
        chdir $child;
        find_terminal_directories_helper($abs_child, $wanted);  # recursion!
        chdir "..";
    }
    push @$wanted, abs_path($dir) if ! $count;  # no sub-directories found!
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
use File::Find;

use strict;
use warnings;

my @dirs;
my %has_children;

find(sub {
    if (-d) {
        push @dirs, $File::Find::name;
        $has_children{$File::Find::dir} = 1;
    }
}, 'D:/Temp');

my @ends = grep {! $has_children{$_}} @dirs;

print "$_\n" for (@ends);
```

Comment: but index of elements are not as i am expecting. For me first element should be $dir[0] = "D:/Temp/A1/B1/C1" but as per your code am getting  $dir[0] = "D:/Temp".

Comment: @drp - So, you want only the full paths to those folders that do not themselves have child folders?

Comment: If you don't want the directories that have children dirs, then you can just filter them out.  Post edited to take that into account.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the following will be helpful:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find::Rule;

my $dir = "D:/Temp";
local $/;

my @dirs =
  sort File::Find::Rule->exec( sub { File::Find::Rule->directory->in($_) == 1 }
  )->directory->in($dir);

for my $dir (@dirs) {
    for my $file (<"$dir/*">) {
        open my $fh, '<', $file or die $!;
        my $data = <$fh>;
        close $fh;
        print $data;
    }
}
```

- `local $/;` lets us *slurp* the file's contents into a variable.  Delete it if you only want to read the first line.
- The `sub` in the `exec()` is used to pass only those dirs which don't contain a dir
- `sort` is used to arrange those dirs in your wanted order
- A file [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) `<"$dir/*">` is used to get the files in each dir

**Edit**: Have modified the code to find only 'terminal directories.'  Thanks to [DavidRR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1497596/davidrr) for this spec clarification.

Comment: The OP clarified that he wants to process *only* what I call **terminal directories**...that is those directories that do not themselves contain directories. (See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20558829/1497596).) `File::Find::Rule` is quite powerful...can you 'easily' revise your answer to add the additional filtering to keep only the terminal directories?

Comment: @DavidRR - I missed this spec, and appreciate your clarification of it.  Have modified the script accordingly.

Comment: Excellent! And here's the perldoc for [File::Find::Rule](http://search.cpan.org/~rclamp/File-Find-Rule-0.33/lib/File/Find/Rule.pm).

Comment: @DavidRR - Your answer helped me lot. Now i have 1 more question. With your code i'll get terminal directory, in that there are many binary files. I supposed to read one file at a time until end of dir after that it should rollover to immediate next dir. Here some times new files keep on adding to this current working dir. I used array to copy files into it, but when new files added to this directory, will not available in array. Please help how to do this. File naming convention is "second-microsec.extension"

Comment: **drp** - I think you meant to get the attention of **Kenosis**. His very concise answer certainly deserves your consideration. Note that `$file` contains the **full path** to each file in each terminal folder. (I have also updated my answer to demonstrate this.) I hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`File::Find`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File%3a%3aFind)

Sample script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; 
use warnings;

use File::Find;

my $dir = "/home/chris";

find(\&wanted, $dir);

sub wanted {
    print "dir: $File::Find::dir\n";
    print "file in dir: $_\n";
    print "complete path to file: $File::Find::name\n";
}
```

OUTPUTS:

```
$ test.pl
dir: /home/chris/test_dir
file in dir: test_dir2
complete path to file: /home/chris/test_dir/test_dir2
dir: /home/chris/test_dir/test_dir2
file in dir: foo.txt
complete path to file: /home/chris/test_dir/test_dir2/foo.txt
...
```

Comment: [File::Find::Rule](http://search.cpan.org/~rclamp/File-Find-Rule-0.33/lib/File/Find/Rule.pm) is built on File::Find.

Answer (score -1):

Using backticks, write subdirs and files to a file called filelist:

```
`ls -R $dir > filelist`
```

Comment: How does the OP do this within a Windows environment?